# Component not re-rendering when useState hook updates

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-query

```
export default function SearchPage() {
    const [searchString, setSearchString] = React.useState("");
    const [apiCall, setApiCall] = React.useState<() => Promise<Collection>>();
    const {isIdle, isLoading, isError, error, data} = useApi(apiCall);
    const api = useContext(ApiContext);

    useEffect(()=>console.log("APICall changed to", apiCall), [apiCall]);

    const doSearch = (event: React.FormEvent) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        setApiCall(() => () => api.search(searchString));
    };

    const doNext = () => {
        var next = api.next;
        if (next) {
            setApiCall(()=>(() => next)());
        }
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    const doPrev = () => {
        if (api.prev) {
            setApiCall(() => api.prev);
        }
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }

    return (
        <>
            <form className={"searchBoxContainer"} onSubmit={doSearch}>
                <TextField
                    label={"Search"}
                    variant={"filled"}
                    value={searchString}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    className={"searchBox"}
                    InputProps={{
                        endAdornment: (
                            <IconButton onClick={() => setSearchString("")}>
                                <ClearIcon/>
                            </IconButton>
                        )
                    }}
                />
                <Button type={"submit"} variant={"contained"} className={"searchButton"}>Go</Button>
            </form>

            {
                (isIdle) ? (
                    <span/>
                ) : isLoading ? (
                    <span>Loading...</span>
                ) : isError ? (
                    <span>Error: {error}</span>
                ) : (
                    <Paper className={"searchResultsContainer"}>
                        <Box className={"navButtonContainer"}>
                            <Button variant={"contained"}
                                    disabled={!api.prev}
                                    onClick={doPrev}
                                    className={"navButton"}>
                                {"< Prev"}
                            </Button>
                            <Button variant={"contained"}
                                    disabled={!api.next}
                                    onClick={doNext}
                                    className={"navButton"}>
                                {"Next >"}
                            </Button>
                        </Box>
                        <Box className={"searchResults"}>
                            {
                                data && data.items().all().map(item => (
                                    <span className={"thumbnailWrapper"}>
                                    <img className={"thumbnail"}
                                         src={item.link("preview")?.href}
                                         alt={(Array.from(item.allData())[0].object as SearchResponseDataModel).title}/>
                                </span>
                                ))
                            }
                        </Box>
                        <Box className={"navButtonContainer"}>
                            <Button variant={"contained"}
                                    disabled={!api.prev}
                                    onClick={doPrev}
                                    className={"navButton"}>
                                {"< Prev"}
                            </Button>
                            <Button variant={"contained"}
                                    disabled={!api.next}
                                    onClick={doNext}
                                    className={"navButton"}>
                                {"Next >"}
                            </Button>
                        </Box>
                    </Paper>
                )
            }
        </>
    )
}
```

For various reasons, I've got a function stored in my state (it's for use with the `react-query` library). I'm seeing very odd behaviour when I try and update it, though. When any of `doSearch`, `doNext`, or `doPrev` are called, it successfully updates the state - the `useEffect` hook is firing properly and I can see the message in console - but it's not triggering a re-render until the window loses and regains focus.

Most of the other people I've seen with this problem have been storing an array in their state, and updating the array rather than creating a new one - so the hooks don't treat it as a new object, and the re-render doesn't happen. I'm not using an array, though, I'm using a function, and passing it different function objects. I'm absolutely stumped and have no idea what's going on.

EDIT: It seems it might not be the rendering failing to fire, but the query hook not noticing that its input has changed? I've edited the code above to show the whole function, and my custom hook is below.

```
function useApi(func?: () => Promise<Collection>) {
    return useQuery(
        ["doApiCall", func],
        func || (async () => await undefined),
        {
            enabled: !!func,
            keepPreviousData: true
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: If the hook fires then it should be re-rendering. Maybe the `stuff` is not re-rendering for other reasons? Can you try to debug/console.log at the top of the component to check if the function gets executed when you expect it to be?

Comment: Hrm. That log statement fired just before the hook log statement, so maybe it is re-rendering, and it's the query hook that's not noticing the update? One moment, I'll add more code

Comment: I don’t see any `react-query` involvement in the posted code. Also, i doubt that you need to store a function in state for react-query. Doing api calls in useEffect is also not idiomatic react-query. Can you describe your use case or show the react-query code please

Comment: The useEffect call was purely for debugging purposes

Comment: My use case is that I'm trying to do react-query based interaction with an API, and deal with the fact that the pagination links are returned in the API response rather than being passable as query parameters to useQuery, while attempting to keep the component completely ignorant of all actual interaction with the api as I want to be able to completely encapsulate all code directly talking to the server and have the component communicate with it purely through a dumb interface

Comment: I see two solutions: extract the pagination info in `onSuccess` and store it in a useState, or `useInfiniteQuery`, which gives you a `getNextPageParam` option for exactly the case when the API returns pagination info as part of the response.

Comment: Ah! `useInfiniteQuery` looks like it might be exactly what I need, thank you!

Comment: That said, I do want pagination rather than an infinite scroll, and I'm not sure how to do that with `useInfiniteQuery` from looking at the docs

Comment: right. useInfiniteQuery will still give you all pages, so you could do it with that, but re-fetches will be tailored for an infinite scroll (re-fetching all pages that you have). The docs suggest `useQuery` with `keepPreviousData: true`. See this example: https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/pagination

The current page is stored in `useState` and is incremented when the user clicks on the "next page" button, but you can also update it depending on data from the server. I made a minimal example: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-kilby-vwkgd?file=/pages/index.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t put a function into the queryKey. Keys need to be serializable. See: https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/query-keys#array-keys

Comment: Accepting this answer as it's almost certainly the reason why my query isn't updating!